# VSCode: "Markdown Preview" SHIFT-COMMAND-P not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts, preview, keymapping

### Setup:

VSCode 1.50.1
MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6) - but I think this applies to any OS

### Steps to Reproduce:

this is a quick simple one...

1. click on/hghlight/open a markdown file (.MD extension) in VSCode / from the Explorer tree hierarchy in the Left Nav Pane,
2. hit `SHIFT-COMMAND-V` per numerous instructional posts/tutorials - (you can also find the shortcut clearly labeled with that very same Shortcut Key-Combo:

   - if you `RIGHT-CLICK` on the file in question...
   - you will get a **Context Menu** with several options, include ***Markdown Preview***
3. hitting the stated key combo of `SHIFT-COMMAND-V` does nothing,i.e.:

   - no observable effect in current window or tab
   - does not open any other tabs
   - does not render markdown

Answer (score 8):

> BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING:
> --
> **This may seem STUPID/OBVIOUS to most of you... I think I was still asleep when I first tried this...** *so*:
>
> 1. make sure that your cursor is *ACTIVE* in your **.MD markdown document**, and ***NOT*** active on the ***filename*** in the Explorer
>    Tree in the left-hand Nav
>
> - apparently, in VSCode this shortcut `SHIFT-COMMAND-V` only works when you are ACTIVELY EDITING the file.
> - using the mouse on the RIGHT-CLICK context menu works fine
>
>   - even if the .MD file isn't open AT ALL / in ANY EDITOR
>   - even if you're actually actively editing A DIFFERENT FILE, if you hover over the filename in the Explorer/File-Folder Hierarchy,
>     RIGHT-CLICK and launch Mark Preview, it will work.

### Quick Solution:

- You most likely have a VSCode **"Extension"** installed and enabled within VSCode that is blocking the default VSCode shortcuts
- in my case, this was **Atom Keymap Extension** ([Here's link to extension in VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.atom-keybindings))
- IN VSCode, go to Extensions, find (you can search in the search bar at the top of the Extensions list/Nav Pane) Atom Keymap and *UNINSTALL IT*
- alternately, you can just simplt *DISABLE IT* if you prefer to use it another time.
- **restart** VSCode
- `SHIFT-COMMAND-V` shortcut **SHOULD BE WORKING NOW!**

### Troubleshooting:

1. Key Combo not recognized in VSCode (at least in VSCode, see#2 if blocked elsewhere)

   - If you look at the very bottom-middle/bottom-right of the VSCode window, you will notice the **Status Bar** (by default the whole bar is bright blue with white text)..
   - the status bar has several different sections, symbols, and text messages...
   - you will notice it changes/will indicate when you press a VALID Key-Combo... and that `SHIFT-COMMAND-V` literally does not result in ANY message on the status bar
   - But hitting `COMMAND-V` for instance ***is reflected*** in a real-time  corresponding message in the status bar telling you that you DID press `COMMAND-V`
   - It appears ***NOT for any Key-Combo*** that includes `SHIFT` isn't recognized
2. confirm it's a VSCode thing only

   - go to your MacOS **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts** > look through each category of shortcuts - you should ***NOT SEE a key mapping*** for `SHIFT-COMMAND-V`

Comment: Nothing was working for me; when I did CTRL+SHIFT+P and searched for markdown, it yielded no results, and I couldn't find a way to open the preview pane. Your first suggestions didn't help. But then when I got to right-clicking the .md file in the files pane, it showed Preview, and I clicked it, and got a preview!  Then everything started working again!  Upvoted!

Comment: Yay @pabrams - your tip about right-clicking the file and choosing preview was the only thing that worked for me. Reloading from the command pallet keeps failing